# Preventing Application Pool from shutting down my web service

Tags: c#, asp.net

A request comes in and my web service get called. Sometimes it takes it an hour and half to do its processing done. Lets say no more request comes in after that, so application pool thinks it is inactive and shuts it down after 20 minutes timeout or so.
Inside my web service I call me method inside a `Task.Facotry.StartNew().`
Now is there a way for this to prevent application pool from Shutting it down if the status of task is not completed yet?

Comment: The normal way of solving this is to have a 2nd application running that is not part of the app pool that does the long processing.

Comment: Why don't you get your [webmaster](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) to just configure the app pool to stay alive?

Comment: Idleness is *one* reason why IIS may decide to shut down an application pool process. You just shouldn't assume that the worker process is a long-lived one.

Answer (score 2):

There a few ways, but the easiest I've found is to just spin up a separate thread that runs in an endless loop with some sort of exit flag condition and so keeps the thread alive and running indefinitely for the lifetime of the application. A scheduler like this is simple enough to create:

```
/// <summary>

/// This is the manager class that handles running the email operation on a background thread

/// </summary>

public class Scheduler : IDisposable

{

    /// <summary>

    /// Determines the status fo the Scheduler

    /// </summary>        

    public bool Cancelled

    {

        get { return _Cancelled; }

        set { _Cancelled = value; }

    }

    private bool _Cancelled = false;





    /// <summary>

    /// The frequency of checks against hte POP3 box are 

    /// performed in Seconds.

    /// </summary>

    private int CheckFrequency = 180;



    EmailForwarder Forwarder = new EmailForwarder();



    AutoResetEvent WaitHandle = new AutoResetEvent(false);



    object SyncLock = new Object();



    public Scheduler()

    {



    }



    /// <summary>

    /// Starts the background thread processing       

    /// </summary>

    /// <param name="CheckFrequency">Frequency that checks are performed in seconds</param>

    public void Start(int checkFrequency)

    {

        this.Forwarder.DeleteMessages = App.Configuration.DeletePop3Messages;            



        // *** Ensure that any waiting instances are shut down

        //this.WaitHandle.Set();



        this.CheckFrequency = checkFrequency;

        this.Cancelled = false;



        Thread t = new Thread(Run);

        t.Start();

    }



    /// <summary>

    /// Causes the processing to stop. If the operation is still

    /// active it will stop after the current message processing

    /// completes

    /// </summary>

    public void Stop()

    {

        lock (this.SyncLock)

        {

            if (Cancelled)

                return;



            this.Cancelled = true;

            this.WaitHandle.Set();

        }

    }



    /// <summary>

    /// Runs the actual processing loop by checking the mail box

    /// </summary>

    private void Run()

    {

        this.Forwarder.LogMessage("...Starting Service",true);



        // *** Start out  waiting

        this.WaitHandle.WaitOne(this.CheckFrequency * 1000, true);



        while (!Cancelled)

        {

            if (App.Configuration.LogDetail)

                 this.Forwarder.LogMessage("...Checking mailbox...", true);



            if (!this.Forwarder.ProcessMessages())

                this.Forwarder.LogMessage("...Processing failed: " + Forwarder.ErrorMessage, false);

            else

            {

                if (App.Configuration.LogDetail)

                    this.Forwarder.LogMessage("...Processing completed", true);

            }



            // *** Http Ping to force the server to stay alive 

            this.PingServer();



            // *** Put in 

            this.WaitHandle.WaitOne(this.CheckFrequency * 1000,true);



        }



        this.Forwarder.LogMessage("...Shutting down service", true);

    }



    public void PingServer()

    {

        try

        {

            WebClient http = new WebClient();

            string Result = http.DownloadString(App.Configuration.PingUrl);

        }

        catch (Exception ex)

        {

            string Message = ex.Message;

        }

    }





    #region IDisposable Members



    public void Dispose()

    {

        this.Stop();

    }



    #endregion

}
```

Comment: How does this solve the OP's problem? Is this supposed to be inside the web service?? Or is this an example of a secondary application which does the heavy processing???